# How to install a single new ubuntu os removing a dual boot os system?

Tags: xubuntu

I currently own a system with Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual boot. I want to remove the entire dual boot system and install a single Ubuntu OS.

Can I directly install Ubuntu via the flash drive without bothering about the dual boot partitions (I don't want the previous OS Windows 7 and Ubuntu partions)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and it's very easy.

1. Download an Ubuntu OS iso. [Click me](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
2. Create a bootable USB drive. [Click](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for explanation from ubuntu.com. The documentation explains also how to create it from a Linux distribution. I'm sorry but I can't post that link, I don't have enough reputation.
3. Insert the USB drive and boot it. For this step, you can just restart and press the boot key for your motherboard (usually F8) and select the USB drive. Otherwise, enter the BIOS and then, in the Boot Menu, put the USB drive to the top.
4. The OS will boot and you can choose between "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu". You can try it live if you want, but a direct installation is the best solution in most of the cases.
5. The only thing you need to change is the partition table. When asked, select "Something Else". Now you can edit your partitions. If you want to erase all other partitions, just select every partition and click the - symbol to delete it.

**WARNING: THIS WILL DELETE ALL THE FILES IN THE PARTITION. BE SURE TO HAVE A BACKUP OF YOUR IMPORTANT DATA.**

6. Now you only have free space. Click the + symbol to add partitions. You'll need 3 partitions for a standard setup: a 20~30GB ext4 partiton with mount point set to /. A 2048MB (= 2GB) partiton as swap area. A xxGB (remaining space) ext4 partition with mount point set to /home.

You're done. Complete the installation and you have your Ubuntu OS with nothing more.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer? I'm new and I need reputation for doing stuff ^^

Answer (score 0):

All your data and files on Windows and Ubuntu and shared data partitions will be lost! Make a backup.

If you want to overwrite everything you can choose the corresponding option in the installation menu or partition manually.

Tip: You should think about whether you want to change from `msdos` to `gpt` partition table using `gparted` in the live distribution before you install. It makes sense to think about it is you make such a drastic change.